What's the name of a 90's movie with Vampires and their beautiful line of girls who get murdered after sex
Long ago I had watched this movie, particularly this scene where 4 guys are with one blonde, red dress and black skirt, in bed and all are enjoying using her at the same time, meanwhile the boss of the pack is convincing to his friend, who is in the room, to join them, while kissing the girl's belly and legs. It goes on to get gruesome where they bite her neck with dog like teeth and kill her, like the many girls they would kill in the movie, finally revealing their true selves somewhere in the middle or after.
Any idea which movie I'm rambling about? I saw this on TV in 2004-05, so it must be a 90's or 00-01 year movie.

I believe the movie you are looking for is Embrace Of The Vampire
The girl in question is Alyssa Milano

It's the closest anyone has gotten to answering this, but...after a WIKI check this is not the movie I was looking for. Thank You @Tivep

dang! Will continue trying.
