10yr old orphan plays music on stage to reunite his parents, pretty famous movie
This one movie where the poor guy falls for the rich girl, have a relationship, but the girls father takes her away after learning she is pregnant. The baby is dumped in an orphanage  who grows up with the one music tone created by his father. When the kid is around 10 he leaves in search of his parents, and when his mother comes in search of her son(shown in trailer, the receptionist asks the boy's name, and the mother tells she doesn't know), she meets the boys father(her old lover) and finally due to turn of events, the kid performs the song on stage, i think in NY. 
Any idea which movie this is ? Supposed to be famous.  

Sounds like August Rush from 2007 with Keri Russell, Terrence Howard and Robin Williams. From IMDb:

The story of a charismatic young Irish guitarist and a sheltered young cellist who have a chance encounter one magical night above New York's Washington Square, but are soon torn apart, leaving in their wake an infant, August Rush, orphaned by circumstance. Now performing on the streets of New York and cared for by a mysterious stranger, August uses his remarkable musical talent to seek the parents from whom he was separated at birth.

August's mother searches for him, finally finding his father and then August himself as he performs in NY. Here's the trailer:




@Walt-Do you know this one ? http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/26307/whats-the-name-of-a-90s-movie-with-vampires-and-their-beautiful-line-of-girls

How can i miss to answer this.....i know this just by reading title.

@SandySands Sounds familiar but can't place it, sorry

@Walt-Thanks anyways.

@Ankit-Hey, that's alright, maybe you can tell me this movie:http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/26307/whats-the-name-of-a-90s-movie-with-vampires-and-their-beautiful-line-of-girls
